# Struts2: test equality of <s:property/> to a variable from action

Tags: struts2

I am trying to test:

```
<s:if test="%{selectedLanguage == <s:property/>}">
```

Where selectedLanguage comes from the action, and s:property is the current object.
In a iterator like this:

```
<s:iterator value="languages">
    <s:if test="%{selectedLanguage == <s:property/>}">
        <option id="<s:property/>" selected><s:property/></option>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <option id="<s:property/>"><s:property/></option>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

Obviously,it doesnt work. How can I solve?

Comment: why you are doing this using <s:property> since object in in `VS`, you can do something like `<s:if test="%{selectedLanguage == myValue}">`

Comment: who is myValue ? I need the instance of "languages" :)

Comment: i believe `myValue` is the value you have in the `valueStack`.when you are iterating the object the current object will be pushed in to top of stack so if your object have property namely `myValue`, you can refer to that directly

Comment: an instance of "languages" doesnt have any property. it's just a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without fixing things, just use the `var` attribute to give the object of iteration a name:

```
<s:iterator value="languages" var="language">
    <s:if test="%{selectedLanguage == #language}">
        <option id="<s:property/>" selected><s:property/></option>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <option id="<s:property/>"><s:property/></option>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

You could also just use `#top` to get the top of the stack, but I think naming it is more communicative.

I'd recommend setting a `selected` attribute based on `#language` or just use the select tag.

Comment: One more related question: suppose I have a <form action="mypage.jspa"> ... and I want to append parameters to the link, mypage.jspa?lang=myLanguage, how do I write that, if myLanguage comes from an action? I tried <form method=post action="saveSynonyms.jspa?lang=%{myLanguage}"> but it is not working

Comment: @Madrugada That's not related at all. I don't know if the action is an OGNL expression. Also not sure why you're submitting to a JSP, unless that's just a weird action extension. In any case, why not just put it in a hidden form element?

Comment: Using a var is by far the most sensible one day I was playing around with reflection... you can use "this" but I think you used to have to call it "#this" and if I recall it wasn't quite that simple... but there is a way to do it.